# Makefile won't copy .o to obj/ and target to bin/ folders

Tags: makefile, executable, x86-64, nasm, object-files

I'm trying to write a Makefile which will copy its target and objects to bin/ and obj/ directories, respectively.

Yet, when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs main.asm -l spacelander.lst
ld -o spacelander obj/main.o
ld: cannot find obj/main.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [spacelander] Error 1
Why is this happening?
```

**Update**

I noticed when I posted the error that it was due to white spacing errors. After taking care of those, I still get the new error I replaced with the old one I mentioned prior.

What is this??

**Update 2**

Posted `-d` flag output below Makefile source.

---

**Source**

```
ASM  := nasm
ARGS := -f
FMT  := elf64
OPT  := -g -F stabs

SRC    := main.asm

OBJDIR := obj 
TARGETDIR := bin

OBJ    := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(patsubst %.asm, %.o, $(wildcard *.asm)))
TARGET := spacelander

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJDIR) $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR): 
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRC)
    $(ASM) $(ARGS) $(FMT) $(OPT) $(SRC) -l $(TARGET).lst

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    ld -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ)

clean:
    @rm -f $(TARGET) $(wildcard *.o)
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
```

**`make -d` Output - NOTE: output is too many characters for body, thus is pastebinned**

http://pastebin.com/3bctGJxs

Comment: Which lines are 29 and 32? Does make with the  -d  give anything notable?

Comment: You probably need to specify the output file from `nasm`, maybe using `-o $@` as an additional option (but you'll have to read the manual to be sure).  This is analogous to the `-o output.o` used with compilers such as `gcc`.

Comment: In the `$(TARGET): $(OBJ)` instruction you mean?

Answer (score 1):

What [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) said in comments is correct. Your `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRC)` rule compiles your source into an object file, but you're not telling `nasm` where to save that object file. This explains exactly why you get the linking error regarding `obj/main.o` not being found by your linker - because `nasm` didn't know it should save it in `obj/main.o`. Try adding `-o <output>`, e.g:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRC)
    $(ASM) $(ARGS) $(FMT) -o $@ $(OPT) $(SRC) -l $(TARGET).lst
```

This answer is marked as *community wiki*. Any gratitudes should go to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler).